# Websphere Application startup error

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I am using Websphere 7 and recently i am getting this error while trying to start the application.

```
00000018 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0100E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet Application Initialization Servlet in application xxx-Portal: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xyz.zyx.web.init.ApplicationInitServlet.init(ApplicationInitServlet.java:75)
```

and the code is :

```
final Properties props =
            init.initialize(url, getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes"));
```

Don't know what happened all of a sudden..Something i have to change in the server parameters since I cannot change the code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple:

Go to installed applicaton > class loader and update detection > under WAR Class loader policy, select 'Single Class Loader'

Now the application will start.

Found it after long struggle .